# "fatal signup error" when creating scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, salesforcedx-cli-auth

I have a Dev Hub that is set up in my Developer Edition org. I have been using it for DX development for several weeks, but when I tried to create a scratch org today with the same configuration file (see below) I received this error in the terminal:

> ERROR: A fatal signup error occurred. Please try again. If you still see this error, contact Salesforce Support for assistance. sfdx-project.json.

The command I am runnning is:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a MyScratchOrg11
```

I have re-authenticated with the Dev Hub org to confirm that I had the correct password, but the error persists. These are the contents of the project-scratch-def.json file I am referencing:

```
{
    "orgName": "myCompanyName Company",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled"]
    }
}
```

The error occurred even after I created a new DX project, created a new Developer Edition org, and re-installed Salesforce DX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any other details in the error message? There are a lot of discussions around scratch org signups on the official Salesforce DX group page today: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1

Most folks are getting the error "The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: C-9999", though your error is slightly different.

The Salesforce team is actively looking into this issue and updating the threads over there, so it might be best to watch that group today.

**Update**: This issue appears to be fixed - can you try creating your scratch org again and report back if you are still having issues?

Comment: Yes, this issue seems to be resolved now.

Comment: We are still encountering this issue. Not yet close.

Comment: Also this week have same issue